# Is a reduplicated verb necessary after "ba3"?

Tags: grammar, usage

In my textbook there's an exercise in which I must decide if a sentence is correct. There's this: 请把这些汉字练. In the answers they say it's incorrect because "lian4" should be reduplicated. Is it really a mistake? I always thought reduplicating a verb is optional, is a matter of what you really want to say (if you want to soften the sentence or not).

Comment: 请把这些汉字练 sounds incomplete.  请把这些汉字练练 or 请把这些汉字练一练/下 is the right way in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote from "Chinese an essential grammar":

> ......, a 把 construction must have an object of definite reference (shifted now to a pre-verbal position directly after 把); **a complement of some kind after the verb** to
>   indicate the result achieved by the action of the verb, either intentionally
>   or unintentionally, on the part of the subject. ......

Quote from "Chinese Grammar Wiki": [Key Things to Keep in Mind When Using 把](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Using_%22ba%22_sentences#Key_Things_to_Keep_in_Mind_When_Using_.E6.8A.8A):

> 把字句 are most often used to describe what happened to the object in some detail. **The verb is not just "bare"; there's "more stuff" after it.** Often the "stuff" is related to some kind of manipulation of the object.

The 把 structure just does not work with a bare verb. Reduplicating the verb also works, as it also adds some information (compliment) to the verb.

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence is just unfinished. 把 is baffling!

请你们练习写一下这些汉字。

请把这些汉字练习写一下。

请把这些汉字练练一下。

Answer (score 0):

請把這些漢字練 is incomplete. There is somethings absent after 練。

To fix this problem, I will try to "fill" the absence with words.

請把這些漢字練熟, 請練這些漢字 or as former people suggested 請把這些漢字練一練 are sufficient to make the sentence complete.